# How to control Spotify via another computer on the same network?

Tags: networking, music, spotify

I'm want to use Spotify as a jukebox accessible by all the computers on a network. I have it installed on 1 computer on the network which has a regular user. I want a way for other network users to control Spotify (at least stop/start/queue music) from their computers. This should not interfere with the usage of the 'jukebox' computer (so VNC/teamview/remote assist is out of the question).

Does anyone know if there are is any software out there that provides this facility?

Comment: You can use the mobile spotify app to control a mac/pc, but I don't think it's possible from another mac/pc without 3rd party help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not what you intend to do, but, have you tried with teamviewer or some other remote control apps like that one? It works fine between computers (that is actually what i do). You can download it here: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx
You'd actually be controlling the whole computer, not just the app... but, if you're desperate... Hope it helps.

I'm subscribing to this question :). I'd like to control spotify on my android phone from my computer, so I guess whatever answer you get might help me.

(sorry if my answer is not best, it's my first)

Comment: Would pick vnc over teamviewer for local control of an application.